# Did the word circle come from the PIE word *kr-kr, which was said to be the Proto-Indo-European word for circular?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european

When I was reading on Wiktionary, I found something interesting. The word for circle was traced back to a Greek word which was said to be "of Pre-Greek origin". However, I read about the word carcer, and found this:

**From Proto-Italic *karkros, from Proto-Indo-European *kr-kr- (“circular”), reduplication of *(s)ker- (“to turn, bend”) in the sense of "enclosure".**

This shows that, considering the fact that both words have "cr" in them and the letter c repeated twice, doesn't that mean that the word was (maybe or probably) from Proto-Indo-European which was inherited to Greek, Latin, Old French, and then English?

Note: this is bold because the normal * won't work.

Comment: See [_*kʷel-_](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/roots.aspx?type=Indo-European&root=k%ca%b7el-). Wiktionary is not a reliable source or etymological information. BTW, if you put a * before an underscore _, then text, then another underscore at the end, you get an asterisk before italicized text. Just the way it works here.

Comment: @jlawler, but the link you gave is reliable? At least wiktionary includes a big disclaimer saying that the reconstructions are speculative to an uncertain degree. And at least they try to reference their claims

Comment: I do have stipulations in mind that so far concerned a hypothetic \*kʷ > *r* / *w* shift, comparing *road* / G *Rad* vs *way* and *wagon* and then some (I'm aware that doesn't make *any* sense to you). Indeed, Sanskr *chakra* "set of wheels" is said to be from \*kʷe*kʷlos, so the idea of fricatives can't be entirely non-sensical. Of course, fricatives are somewhat difficult to explain in English.

Comment: The PIE roots in the the free dictionary are from the American Heritage Dictionary of Indo-European Roots, which is largely Pokorny. That's as authoritative and non-speculative as it gets.

Comment: You can escape a star character with a backslash: `\*` is rendered \*